# Compilation Error when trying to access Result of a Task in ContinueWith

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task, task-parallel-library

I am using .NET 4.0 (so no async and await) and am trying to use this in a ViewModel of WPF UI project.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
     () => _someObject.Start(), 
     CancellationToken.None, 
     TaskCreationOptions.None, 
     TaskScheduler.Default)
  .ContinueWith(
     prevTask => FollowUpAction(prevTask.Result), 
     Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
```

Here signature of `_someObject.Start` is `bool Start()` and signature of `FollowUpAction` is `void FollowUpAction(bool)`

But when I am trying to compile the code, I am getting the following

> error : error CS1061: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a
> definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a
> first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Basically, I am not able to access the Result of the previous task when I am trying to chain it up with a continuation task.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why you need `ContinueWith` if you can pass it directly as argument? `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FollowUpAction(_someObject.Start()), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);`

Comment: This would only return this error if the `Start` signature was `void`, if it were `bool` there would be seemingly no problems and `Result` would be valid. Task has no `Result`, only `Task<T>`

Comment: OP said: "Here signature of `_someObject.Start` is `bool Start()`"

Comment: My money is on `Start` being `void`

Comment: `bool Start` is not `Task<bool> Start` so it hasn't any `Result` property, only returned value of `true` or `false`

Comment: @TheGeneral No, Start actually returns bool.

Comment: @Auditive, I am trying to execute the Start method in the backgroud (non UI thread) and FollowupAction in UI thread, hence the chaining with a different TaskScheduler.

Comment: Trouble is in `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` in `ContinueWith`. There probably should be `CancellationToken.None`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iiLFPl

Comment: @Auditive Actually there is an overloaded method, no there shouldnt be a problem. However, I still tried .ContinueWith(
     prevTask => FollowUpAction(prevTask.Result), 
     CancellationToken.None, 
     TaskCreationOptions.None, 
     Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher); 
Still the same error.

Comment: There is no overload for `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` as 2nd argument in `ContinueWith` (in total or 2 arguments).

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the error message. `System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not`: Where is the generic? Shouldnt it be something like `Task<Type>`?

Comment: @TheGeneral I saw the code in, any chance, there is difference in .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar maybe just checking... Not that I can see

Comment: @Auditive There is. However, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() doesnt help either. I am sure that is not the problem with respect to Compilation error.

Comment: `.ContinueWith((prevTask, obj) => FollowUpAction(prevTask.Result), Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);`

Comment: @Klamsi Exactly. I expect a Task<bool> from the StartNew, so that I can access its result in ContinueWith

Comment: Look at `(prevTask, obj) =>`, not `prevTask =>`

Comment: Signature you trying to use looks like: `public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task<TResult>, object> continuationAction, object state)`. You passed only `Task<TResult>`, without `object`.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar first, .NET 4.0 went out of support *many* years ago. The oldest supported version is 4.5.2 although by May 2022 all versions below 4.6.2 will reach End-Of-Life. Second, you **can use async** by using the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package. That's no less supported than using .NET 4.0

Comment: @SanthoshKumar in fact, unless you target Windows XP (which also went out of support many years ago) *you ARE NOT targeting .NET 4.0 **at all***. .NET 4.x versions are binary replacements and all supported desktop OSs come with later runtimes. Even on Windows 7 or 8, installing a 4.5+ runtime will replace the 4.0 runtime. That means your application is already running on 4.6 if not later.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar finally, the only way you'd get that error is if `Start` is void. Perhaps you have multiple overrides? Post code that actually reproduces the bug, code that can be copied and produce the bug you claim.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar `Actually there is an overloaded method, no there shouldnt be a problem` obviously not. Post your actual code so people can help you fix it

Comment: @Auditive `ContinueWith` doesn't require any magic, and the result of a `bool` method will appear as a `Task<bool>` in `ContinueWith`. No amount of fiddling with `ContinueWith`'s parameters will change that. The OP is calling the wrong method.